# Drag&Drop во Vue.js, почему некорректно отрабатывает метод elementFromPoint?

Tags: vue.js

Изобретаю велосипед с Drag&Drop (для опыта и всё такое, про готовые библиотеки знаю).

[Делаю по этому примеру.](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pdBkzvuS8BuKPioNC09Z?preview)

Я внес некоторые правки в код, но при копировании их в обычный html файл, всё отрабатывает так, как надо. Однако при запуске этого кода во Vue, код на 40 строке отрабатывает неверно - несмотря на явное задание перетаскиваемому элементу свойства hidden = true, в elemBelow всё равно возвращается перетаскиваемый элемент.

```
clone.hidden = true
let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)
console.log('element below is', elemBelow)
clone.hidden = false
```

Потратил уже пол дня на копание этого вопроса, но успешный запуск в отдельном html файле окончательно сбил меня с толку. Не имею представления, что именно во vue может быть помехой.

В ближайшее время постараюсь оформить codepen с воспроизведением проблемы.

[Вот наглядный пример.](https://codepen.io/andrej-rusinas/pen/wvaGpZo?editors=1111) В консоль выводится значение переменной elemBelow

Comment: вместо аттрибута `hidden`, используйте свойство `display` - все заработает

Comment: @Дмытрык действительно заработало, спасибо! Какая же тупая ситуация. Я искренне верил, что использование hidden, а не style.display в данном кейсе чем-то обусловлено

Comment: Суть этого действа - убрать перетаскиваемый элемент с верхней области просмотра. Видимо, `hidden` - не убирает элемент. По идее, вместо  свойства `display`, можно использовать `z-index`, установив его в глубокий минус.

Comment: @Дмытрык да, в статье Кантора об этом и говорится, и что hidden как-раз должен за это отвечать. Штука в том, что hidden не работает именно во Vue, и это очень странно. Думаю, создать issue на эту тему, вопрос интересный, почему так.

Comment: если создадите - оставьте тут ссылку